# IE doesn't calculate textarea height with line-height

Tags: html, css

I want to display 4 rows for a textarea and set `line-height: 200%`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
1
2
3
4</textarea>
```

and the CSS:

```
textarea {
    line-height: 2;
}
```

IE seems to calculate the height without line-height, and show only 2 rows.
like this：

[ie_textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBbDE.png)

Is there any method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used `height` CSS property to solve this problem.